# Adding a slash to the end of the URL using htaccess

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a `.htaccess` code which is given below.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.vdsta\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin-panel
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule ^admin-panel(?:/(.*))?$ /staging/admin-panel/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.vdsta\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^((?!((vdsta_app/website)|(staging/admin-panel))/).*)$ /vdsta_app/website/$1 [L,NC]
```

The issue is when I type the URL `https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel` it leads me to a blank page. But when I just add a slash like this: `https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel/`, it works fine.

So how can I set in `.htaccess` so that when I type `https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel` it will redirect to `https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel/`?

Comment: `So how can i set in htaccess so that when i type "https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel" and it will redirect to "https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel"` your both shown urls are looking fine, could you please correct them in your question once?

Comment: So how can i set in htaccess so that when i type "https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel" and it will redirect to "https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel/"

It is actually like this. please review.

Comment: Could you please change your `admin-panel` rule to something like `RewriteRule ^admin-panel/(.*)?/?$ /staging/admin-panel/$1 [L]` once and try, make sure you clear your browser's cache and try it. Let me know how it goes then.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I set in `.htaccess` so that when I type `https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel` and it will redirect to `https://app.vdsta.com/admin-panel/`?

You can add the following redirect directive *before* your existing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.vdsta\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin-panel$ /$0/ [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you are linking to the URL *with* the trailing slash throughout your site, otherwise you will get a log of unnecessary redirects.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and only change to a 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this works OK.

The `$0` backreference contains the matched URL-path (ie. `admin-panel`), to which we append a slash for the redirection.

HOWEVER, I would be curious to know *why* this is resulting a "blank page" to begin with? Are you using relative client-side URL-paths (to CSS, JS, images, ...)? The fact that you have tagged the question `javascript` perhaps suggest this is JS related. Otherwise the first internal rewrite directive behaves exactly the same whether a trailing slash was present on the initial request or not - the trailing slash is essentially appended during the internal rewrite. So, *something else* (I guess client-side JS) is resulting in the "blank page".

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin-panel
> ```

This first `RewriteCond` directive is entirely superfluous.